# double layer key in data frame python

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to create a data frame in python which has double key, each key will have 3 subkeys, so to call a value in the data frame i'll need to refer to it with 3 indexes

```
df=[               key1               key2                key3
    index   key11 key12 key13   key21 key22 key23  key31 key32 key33
      0      12    32     45     345    34    43     3     54    134
      1      143   41     14      4      1    13     14    41     43
      2      114   11     54      11    13   13      43    13     13
    ]
```

so to call the '11' in column 2 row 3 it should look like df[2,'key1','key12'].
is there any possibility to do so?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could quite easily set this up with embedded dictionaries and a list. For example:

```
df = {
    'key1' : {
        'key11' : [12, 143, 114],
        'key12' : [32, 41, 14],
        'key13' : [114, 11, 54]},
    'key2' : {
        'key21' : [345, 4, 11],
        'key22' : [34, 1, 13],
        'key23' : [43, 13, 13]},
    'key3' : {
        'key31' : [3, 14, 43],
        'key32' : [54, 41, 13],
        'key33' : [134, 43, 13]}
    }
```

The value that you want would then be `df['key1']['key12'][2]`.
This dictionary could be set up automatically with more info on how your data was coming in.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!
Just need to Add the commas after each line, but basically it works!